# How is Unix signal propagated to PGID in namespaces and what is the impact of NSpgid on process signal handling?

Tags: linux, process, signals, pid

I'm working with Unix signal handling and trying to understand the mechanism behind signal propagation to process groups, especially in the context of Linux namespaces. When I run cat /proc/[pid]/status | grep NSpgid, I get a value that I assume represents the namespace-specific process group ID (NSpgid).

My question is two-fold:

Does the Unix kernel automatically propagate a signal to all child processes sharing the same process group ID (PGID), or is it necessary to manually send signals to each child process within that group?

How does the concept of namespaces (indicated by NSpgid from the /proc/[pid]/status output) affect the delivery and handling of these signals?

What I have tried:

Sending a signal to the parent process ID and observing the behavior of child processes in the same group.
Retrieving NSpgid information from the proc filesystem to discern namespace-specific behavior.

Comment: When you send a signal to a process group (by using a negative PID argument to `kill()`) the kernel takes care of sending to all the processes in the group.

Comment: @Barmar I tried the same but wasn't working for me, a sh -c docker-compose up has nspgid 271979 when I sent it an interrupt signal using ~ "sudo kill -2 -271979 " the same wasn't sent to child process but when I did "sudo kill -2 -- -271979" it was working fine, even without the "-" sign, it was killing the process (I logged the strace and it recieved SIG_INT)

Comment: (OT): the shell does not automatically forward the SIGINT signal to the child process but when I wrote a code in go where I sent  syscall.Kill(pid, sig) in my go code, not only my shell was closed, the child process recieved the signal too, any insight about that?

Comment: That's probably related to session management. If you kill the session leader, all the processes in the session are killed as well.